# Integrating facebook 'compose new message' popup into my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am designing a website that will be heavily integrated with facebook. Members connect to the site via their facebook accounts and facebook authentication/permission is used to access their friends list and other information.

There are instances in which I would like the site to be able to send facebook inbox messages to selected people from the user's friends list (in a user initiated manner).

I have discovered that this is not possible through facebook permissions.

One idea that I have is to have Facebook's "Compose New Message" popup to appear overlayed on top of my site (as would appear when clicking the "Send new message" button on a user's profile page). The user would then type a message and press send (hopefully circumventing the permissions issue).

I have browsed the facebook developer docs and forums, but my technical knowledge is limited. I just want to know if this is possible or not, and to be pointed in the direction of material on how this could be achieved (so that I can pass this on to hired developers once I reach that stage)

Any help or suggestions on alternatives would be gratefully received!

Pete

Comment: Just to clarify, I would like the message to be sent from the user's facebook account, rather than from our facebook app (so that the person receiving the message can see who it is from)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest you can be to your goal is using the [Send Button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/). However, this button is used to share links, which are usually open graph pages. What you can to is specify a dummy href/link so that it shows a blank page. Or, better if you actually needed a link attached, then you have no problem.

There is no way of doing it using Graph API [Message Object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/message/). There are no publishing rights to this object whatever permission you ask from the user. It is read-only. Just look at the extended permission it is only [read_mailbox](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) - "**READ**_mailbox".

Even [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/unified_message/) can't help us with this.

Also, facebook is in the process of migrating to a new messaging system. So playing around with is now is not advisable.

What you can do now is utilize the **Send button** I mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks, I think the send button should meet my needs. When using the send button, is it possible for my site to automatically fill-out the "To" and "Message" fields, based on information that the user has already provided me with? This would prevent them from having to provide the same information twice. Obviously they would be given the option to edit/cancel/send.

Comment: Unfortunately, the send button does not accept such a parameter. The workaround I can think of so that we avoid repetitive action is to remove "To" field input on your side.